# Multi-container docker-compose vs multiple single-container?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

When is a multi-container `docker-compose` project to favor instead of multiple independent single containers?

Especially where the containers themself **don't depend** on each other, except a common db container: I have a project that has a lose-coupled api, scripts and a database.

Now what is better: to **combine** all services in one place (multi-container project), or to **divide** them into separate projects because all of them could theoretically run without the other service.

- *api*: provides external access to db via rest api. must run always.
- *scripts*: runs 1-2x a day triggered via ssh from a legacy product (I cannot change this). Basically exports db data to csv.

Pseudocode:
`/example/docker-compose.yml`:

```
services:
  api:
    #based on custom image (the service runs as the main process)
    build:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile_api
    ports: 5000:5000
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: 'db'
      MYSQL_USER: 'user'
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: 'password'

  scripts:
    #based on custom image (the script runs as the main process, and terminates the container once finished export)
    build:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile_scripts
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: 'db'
      MYSQL_USER: 'user'
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: 'password'
 
  db:
    image: mysql:8.0
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: 'db'
      MYSQL_USER: 'user'
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: 'password'
    volumes: dbdata:/var/lib/mysql

  ui:
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    environment:
      PMA_HOST: db
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password

  volumes:
    dbdata:
```

So: the rest api and the scripts are themselves independent of each other. Still they belong together in this project (eg the API feeds data into the db, thus the export scripts would not be able to extract data being fed before through the API).

But I could as well think of creating a separate separate projects like:

```
/example/api/docker-compose.yml
/example/api/Dockerfile
/example/scripts/docker-compose.yml
/example/scripts/Dockerfile
/example/db/docker-compose.yml (can contain both mysql + phmyadmin)
```

What is better from design perspective, and why?